# Dijkstra's Algorithm Does not generate Shortest Path?

Tags: algorithm, graph-theory, shortest-path, dijkstra

I am working through a shortest path problem using Dijkstra's Algorithm. I am having trouble because the algorithm is supposed to provide the shortest path, but after running the algorithm I get a shorted path by hand. Is this just a by-product of this algorithm?

The path I am trying to generate is from a -> z

[image: unmarked graph]

Here is the path that I get from applying the algorithm, taking the shortest distance jump at each vertex I visit:

```
  2    4    2    2    1    2    1    1    8      = 23
a -> d -> g -> k -> r -> n -> q -> p -> t -> z
```

[image: Marked Graph]

This is confusing to me because if I take this path:

```
  4    2    2    2    2    2    2     = 16
a -> c -> f -> i -> m -> p -> s -> z
```

I get a distance that is 5 less than the distance generated from the algorithm.

Did I misstep somewhere?

Comment: You are implementing the Greedy algorithm, not Dijkstra's.

Comment: this diagram is from kneth Rosen if i am right ...

Comment: @Hunter McMillen : Can you please let me know how did you generate the above graphs. Thank you

Comment: @Chandrasekhar sorry, I scanned them from my textbook so unfortunately I am not sure how to create one. In the past I have used [Dia](http://dia-installer.de/) for similar things.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you misunderstand how Dijkstra's algorithm works. Instead of taking the edge with the smallest weight at each node, you always need to consider the total distance from the beginning (node $a$). You maintain a heap of all possible paths under consideration, which starts off as just the starting node with no edges and expands by adding all the paths with each outgoing edge of a node added to the path you're currently considering at each step.

That's a jumble of words trying to summarise where you went wrong. I suggest re-reading how Dijkstra's algorithm works: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm