# Algorithm/Method Use By Google Maps For Finding the Path Between Two Cities

Tags: google-maps

Recently I had a job interview they asked me "Which method is use by google maps for finding the shortest path between two cities?". I didn't had the answer to that question but I guessed they use the "Shortest Path Algorithm" for finding the path but the interviewer said "No". After that interview I Googled a lot but didn't find any method for that. Please tell me if you have any idea about how google maps find shortest path between two cities

Comment: Did he asked you about shortest path? Then your a right. Read here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10254542/dijkstras-algorithm-does-not-generate-shortest-path?rq=1. But maybe he means the fastest path?

Comment: Did you take a look at this thread? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/430142/what-algorithms-compute-directions-from-point-a-to-point-b-on-a-map

Comment: Sorry I didn't look at that thread.

Comment: You can read this google blog http://googleblog.blogspot.com.br/2007/11/road-to-better-path-finding.html and this great answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/432854/2516160

Answer (score 1):

As it happens I just attended a talk about it. Dijkstras Algorithm is too inefficient for google. Although the complexity, n log n , is fine the absolute time it takes is quite large.

Google uses a variant of [Contraction Hierarchies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contraction_hierarchies). It is faster than Dijkstra because the network is preprocessed. Even though there are faster algorithms out there that involve preprocessing, CH provides a lot of flexibility.

Answer (score 0):

What about A*? It seems suitable for path finding.